# How Can the Same Query in Two Nearly Identical Instances Generate Two Different Execution Plans?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, execution-plan, subquery, functions, cross-apply

Server A and Server B have identical hardware and instance configurations (A is Production, B is QA). B's DBs were restored from A's backups from one week ago. I was provided this query by the development team.

```
SELECT 
        c.Start
        ,c.[End]
        ,c.Word
        ,doc.UniqueDocumentNumber
        ,doc.EID
        ,c.CUI
        ,c.Concept
        ,a.OID
        ,doc.DocumentTypeName
        ,doc.ActivityDtTm
        ,CAST(doc.DocumentTypeId AS INT) AS MedCode
        ,CASE WHEN c.[Count] = 0 THEN  CAST(0.00 AS REAL)
           ELSE CAST(LOG(c.TotalCount / c.[Count]) AS REAL) END AS 'idf'
        ,c.[Count]
        ,c.TotalCount
FROM ECHO..AEID201 a
INNER JOIN ALPHA..XADocuments doc (NOLOCK) ON a.EID = doc.EID
CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.start,t.[end],t.word,t.cui,t.eid,
   t.UniqueDocumentNumber,cu.[Count],cc.TotalCount,core.Concept 
FROM HOTEL.dbo.Htf_Index AS t
INNER JOIN HOTEL..Doc_CUI_Counter AS cu ON cu.CUI=t.CUI AND cu.DocumentTypeID=t.DocumentTypeID
INNER JOIN HOTEL..Doc_Counter AS cc ON cc.DocumentTypeID=t.DocumentTypeID
INNER JOIN HOTEL..CUI_CORE AS core ON core.CUI=cu.CUI
WHERE t.eid = doc.eid AND doc.UniqueDocumentNumber=t.UniqueDocumentNumber
) AS c
WHERE a.OID='00005159-9567-4187-a278-5b8e1e2ed20c' 
AND ISNUMERIC(doc.DocumentTypeId) = 1
```

On Server B, review of the execution plan indicates that the criteria for table [a] at bottom is part of an index seek operation at the start of the execution plan, which makes the subquery [c] resultset execute rapidly.

On Server A, review of the same execution plan indicates that subquery [c] is executing first with full index scans due to outer criteria not being applied.

Indexes utilized in both execution plans are identical. Table rows counts are slightly larger on Server A since the restore due to normal operations but index fragmentation is nearly identical. A participating index on table [t] in the subquery on Server B has double the number of pages as on Server A but identical row count. Statistics are updated nightly at the same time on both servers.

I've attempted index rebuilds on table [t] and manually updating statistics to attempt to get both execution plans to match. What other factors may be causing this change in the order of execution?

I suggested to the developer replacing the subquery with a UDF that takes the EID and UniqueDocumentNumber fields from [doc] as arguments. What other options can I explore with the developer to increase the probability of the execution plans on QA being utilized on Prod?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Execution plans (actual, not estimated) need to be added to the Q for a definitive answer but...

> How Can the Same Query in Two Nearly Identical Instances Generate Two
>   Different Execution Plans?

Because, by your admission, they are not identical. Most likely explanation for the different execution plans is a variance in statistics.

> Table rows counts are slightly larger on Server A... Statistics are
>   updated nightly at the same time on both servers.

Row counts are different and the statistics update was probably a default sample, rather than `FULLSCAN`. I've witnessed some comically unfortunate stats histograms as the result of sampling, each of which has been corrected by a `FULLSCAN` update.